# Question : is there any way to create a form with a JavaScript input

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make a form on the html page with the input field made with JavaScript .

I included the full source code & I'm so sorry if the JS code is big , I didn't write it it's an open source project . I really hope to get some help .

I Hope there is a way to include the input field made with JavaScript to a html form .

Thanks so much !

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta content="IE=edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" />
    <base target="_parent">
    <script>
        if (window.parent !== window) {
            try {
                window.__REACT_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__ = window.parent.__REACT_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__;
            } catch (error) {
                // The above line can throw if we do not have access to the parent frame -- i.e. cross origin
            }
        }
    </script>
    <title>Storybook</title>
    
</head>

<body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <div id="error-display"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://yourjavascript.com/2560291117/preview-0c18dfe69fe4ef4a04bd-bundle.js"></script></body>

</html>
```

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: tried to add <form before the script & a submit bouton after the script but didn't work

Answer (score 0):

```
function addInput() {
  let input = document.createElement("input");
  input.type = "text";
  input.value = "Hello World!";
  document.getElementById("form").appendChild(input);
}
```

The function adds it to the element with id="form", is that what you meant?

Answer (score 0):

After I read your last comment I think I've understood what you are looking for?

```js
(function(){
  
  const form = document.createElement("form");
  form.method = "POST";
  form.action = "";
  
  let fields = [
    {name: "email", type: "email", label: "Email address*", id: "email_input"},
    {name: "password", type:"password", label: "Password*", id: "password_input"},
    {name: "rememberme", type:"checkbox", label: "Remember me?", id: "rememberme_input"}
  ];


  fields.forEach(_ => {
    if( typeof _.label != "undefined" ) {
      const label = document.createElement("label");
      label.setAttribute("for", `${typeof _.id == "string" ? _.id : ""}`);
      label.innerHTML = _.label;
      form.appendChild(label);
    } 
    form.appendChild(
      createInput(
        _.name,
        _.type,
        _.id
      )
    );
  });
  
  
  const button = document.createElement("button");
  button.type = "submit";
  button.innerHTML = "Submit";
  form.appendChild(button);

  document.body.appendChild(form);
  
  
  function createInput(name, type="text", id="") {
    const input = document.createElement("input");
    input.type = type;
    input.name = name;
    input.id = id;
    return input;
  }
  
}());
```

```css
form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-betwee;
  max-width: 350px;
}

form input,
form button {
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta content="IE=edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" />
    <base target="_parent">
    <script>
        if (window.parent !== window) {
            try {
                window.__REACT_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__ = window.parent.__REACT_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__;
            } catch (error) {
                // The above line can throw if we do not have access to the parent frame -- i.e. cross origin
            }
        }
    </script>
    <title>Storybook</title>
    
</head>

<body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <div id="error-display"></div>
    
</body>
</html>
```